# Look for values in column and match

Tags: excel, vba

Got damn it! Im stuck again.

I have tried to do some helper columns to sort out information from 1 column and then show me if there is a similiarity in the value.

What I have now is,

values in column A

```
D3875 HMG XS
D3875 BGE XS
D3874 BGE XS
I3874 BGE XS
```

I want to use to number to see if I have both D and I at the beginning of string because this means that my value is approved.

Edit- There are only some cells in the column that has the same value exept D and I at the beginning. In abowe example it is

```
D3874 BGE XS
I3874 BGE XS
```

Could i somehow ( dont know how right now) lets say make a loop where i take the first value in column A such as D3875 HMG XS and use 3875 HMG XS too loop in the column untill i find a cell with the same value exept that it holds a I instead of D at the beginning?

Comment: When asking a question make sure you put in all required information, Scotts is the best answer for your question, however your edit changed the question enough to make the others answers worthless. In cases like this consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Ah alright! Thanks for the critics! Im new to this so in the future i will take ur tips to use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find if the same number is found with both an I and a D prefix, if so it will return `Approved` if not `Not Approved`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,IF(LEFT(A1,1)="D","I","D")&MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))),"Approved","Not Approved")
```

[image]

---

NOTE:

This only works if `I` and `D` are the only prefixes, or you will get false positives.

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `IF` and `LEFT` to pull the first character and check if its `D` or `I`

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1, 1)="D", LEFT(A1, 1)="I"), "Approved", "Not Approved")
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I saw altough that i was stupid and hadnt printed my collumns correctly! I have some diffrent values in column A but only some numbers has both D and I. SUch as in abowe example, D3874 BGE XS
I3874 BGE XS

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

In Cell B1:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="D","Approved",IF(LEFT(A1,1)="I","Approved","Not Approved"))
```

The result will be:

If the Text in A1 starts with D or I, B1 will say "Approved", otherwise, you guessed it, "Not Approved". Just drag down to reach all required cells. Hope this helps.

Comment: Lol Tim beat me and used a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to achieve the same thing. Although if you ever intend to add more than just two conditions (`I and D`) then I'd go with this:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT(A1),{"D","I"},0)),"Not Approved","Approved")
```

Which you could extend, to include more conditions, in either of these ways

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT(A1),{"D","I","A","B"},0)),"Not Approved","Approved")
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT(A1),A1:A4,0)),"Not Approved","Approved")
```

Where `A1:A4` contains your conditions in the last example.

Comment: This allso works like a charm! U are pros! But i am sorry and i needed to edit my question alittle bit. Some values in the column are diffrent and i would like to check one row value in column to see if it has a I before aswell. Only some rows have both D and I so i would need to look at one row in Column A and see if the value after D can be find with in the column and starts with I. IS it possible?